# React - mapStateToProps function isn't getting called in my todo app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

This is my 2nd day with Redux.

The basic structure of the app is:

```
App
-TodoForm
-TodoList
--TodoListItem
```

The reducer function is getting called but it doesn't call the `mapStateToProps`. I tried `console.log()`. I have used the `react-hot-boilerplate`. Please let me know the reason why the `mapStateToProps` function isn't invoked.

https://github.com/rickieanand/reduxTodo

```jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore} from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'

//store

let store = createStore(todo)


//actions
const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
let x = 1
function addTodo(text) {
    return {
        type: ADD_TODO,
        id: x++,
            text: text
    }
}

//reducer

function todo(state = { id: 0, text: "", completed: false }, action) {
    console.log("reducer Called")
    console.log(action)

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            console.log(Object.assign({}, state, {
                id: action.id,
                text: action.text,
                completed: false
            }) !== state)

            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                id: action.id,
                text: action.text,
                completed: false
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}




//component App
class App extends Component {
    onHandleSubmit(text) {
        console.log('OnHandleSubmit Called')
        store.dispatch(addTodo(text))
        console.log('----------')
        store.getState()
        console.log('----------')
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, world.</h1>
                <TodoForm onHandleSubmit={this.onHandleSubmit}/>
                <TodoList/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps")
    console.log(state)
    console.log(ownProps)
    return {
        text: state.text,
        id: state.id,
        completed: false
    }
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(App)

//component Form

class TodoForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        //            this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this)
    }
    // handleAdd(e){
    // e.preventDefault()
    // console.log(e.target)
    // //dispatch(addTodo(e.value))
    // }
    render() {
        let input
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={e => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    if (!input.value.trim()) {
                        return
                    }
                    console.log(input.value)
                    this.props.onHandleSubmit(input.value)
                    //store.dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
                    //input.value = ''
                } }>
                    <input ref={node => {
                        input = node
                    } } />
                    <button type="submit">
                        Add Todo
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

//component TodoList
class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul><TodoListItem /></ul>
        );
    }
}

//component TodoListItem
class TodoListItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this)
    }
    handleDelete(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.value)
        //this.props.dispatch(addTodo(e.value));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.text}<button id={this.props.id} onClick=   {this.handleDelete}/></li>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: First things first, you're not supposed to have actions, reducers, etc. all in one file. It's probably worth starting again http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/index.html

Comment: I understand, but I thought once things get working, I'll play with the folder structure.

Comment: Try Damien approach, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connect(mapStateToProps)(App)` returns the connected component. Write;

```
const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Then:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><ConnectedApp /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```